# Horizontal autolayout constraint has some strange offset on UIScrollView/UIView

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, ios8.1

Last week I dived into auto layout. While coding my first app today, I faced a strange "bug" with UIScrollView and auto layout. I couldn't find any similar issue on here so I created a new topic.

Here is some example code:

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(view)

    let constraintH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[view]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["view": view])

    // two options fixing this bug: "H:|-0-[view]-0-|" or "H:|[view]|"
    // only horizontal constraint has this issue

    let constraintV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[view]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["view": view])

    self.view.addConstraints(constraintH)
    self.view.addConstraints(constraintV)
```

First I thought the reason was iOS 8.3 Beta SDK, but issue is also present with iOS 8.1 SDK. So is it only me or is it some autolayout bug which I should report to Apple?

**UPDATE:**
I modified the code from UIScrollView to UIView so you can see that this bug is also applied to a normal UIView as well.

[image]

Comment: You've really provided close to zero information about the bug itself. Give us some screenshots or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal spaces is the Margin, which is introduced in iOS 8. You could try to run it on an iOS 7.1 simulator and there would be no margin.

You were right, removing the dashes should fix it

```
let constraintH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["view": view])
```

Also, if you are using a UIScrollView and AutoLayout you should read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: If you could add a quote or a link to some of Apples dev page  where they introduce this margin, I will accept your answer then. But still it is strange that there is no vertical margin for "V:|-[view]-|", and I wonder why is that so.

Comment: according to [link] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) "[button]-[textField]" would produce a standard space of 8

Comment: Still wonder why it does not apply to the vertical constraint. Anyways this is a good answer, I must have overseen it in the docs. Thx.